# Laravel Backpackl - Request Unique Product and Nutrients

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm having a problem with my application. I have a CRUD where I choose a product and assign it nutrients to it, currently I only have 5 nutrintes. I am registering the nutrient and its value correctly, the problem is when I register a nutrinte repeated, instead of showing me an error to the user saying that nutrinte already was, he tries to register and the stick in the bank.

I tried to use unique, being that it bar any nutrinente that I try to register, even if it is new in this product.

How do I check if this nutrinente already exists?

I'm using the Backpack package.

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        'nutrient_id'   =>  'required',
        'portion'       =>  'required|numeric',
        'amount'        =>  'required|numeric',
    ];
}



SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-62' for key 'product_nutritional_facts_nutrient_id_product_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `product_nutritional_facts` (`nutrient_id`, `portion`, `amount`, `product_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 11, 11, 62, 2018-12-14 22:22:41, 2018-12-14 22:22:41))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need separate requests on store and update. Please check the manual: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

On store:

```
public function rules(){
        $id = Input::all()['id'];
        return [
            'nutrient_id'   =>  'required|unique:product_nutritional_facts,nutrient_id,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL' . $id, // remove deleted_at,NULL if you don't use soft deletes
            'portion'       =>  'required|numeric',
            'amount'        =>  'required|numeric',
        ];
    }
```

On update:

```
public function rules(){
    $id = Input::all()['id'];
    return [
        'nutrient_id'   =>  'required|unique:product_nutritional_facts,nutrient_id,' . $id,
        'portion'       =>  'required|numeric',
        'amount'        =>  'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```